# What's are some best practices for responsive images (e.g. for section headers)?

Tags: images, responsive

Silly me is letting a client upload their own header images. I'm checking if they've uploaded something, and if found I add it as a background image with an inline style in the template.

But, how do I swap images based on device used?

Normally, I'd just add media queries and swap out the images in my css, but when they're inline backgrounds, I'm not sure what to do.

How do you handle it?

Comment: Just use (the WP generated) `<img>` tag instead of `background-image`? (see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31267425/use-the-html-img-tag-as-a-background-image-instead-of-the-css-background-image)

Comment: Is that the most popular approach? I like the ease of using center and cover for my bg, and I couldn't replicate it with object-fit yet. I will continue experimenting...

Comment: I don't have any (usage) statistics on it, I know it is a neat tricked used by page builders and other tools that want to have better responsiveness for images. I think an alternative would be to have multiple `div`s inside, each with a specific version of the image, and then displaying either one via media query.

Comment: Cool, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you set background image to some tag inline, you still able to control it with css and media queries, `!important` is still working =)

```
<div id="image" style="background:url(image.jpg);">
```

`!important` still has priority over inline style and you can use in your media queries.

```
#image{
    background:url(another-image.jpg) !important;
}
```